# Por que mi form2 no registra los datos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 forms en un .php ... el 1 es para validar sesion y el segundo para registrar un nuevo usuario, el problema es que el segundo lo tengo configurado por si las contraseñas son incorrectas o los datos se subieron correctamente...Pero por mas de que me sale la alerta de que se ha registrado con exito en mi bd no se registra nada, sin embargo ya cuando logeo tengo otro formulario de registro (diferente diseño) y en ese si me registra los datos en la BD.

He revisado variables una por una, pero por mas que hago no puedo lograr que se suban los datos, cuando es la misma conexion para ambos formularios de registro y en uno si y en otro no me registra....

Dejo mi form del cual no me registra los datos y mi codigo php.

```
<form id="f2" action="Conexion/Conexion_Usuarios2.php" method="post" class="sign-up-form">
                <h2 class="title">Registrate</h2>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="nombre" maxlength="20" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="paterno" maxlength="20" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="materno" maxlength="20" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <script src="js/mainn.js"></script>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input name="correo" maxlength="20" type=" text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                    <input name="telefono" maxlength="10" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="usuario" maxlength="20" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <input name="contra" maxlength="20" type="Password" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <input name="confirmar_contra" maxlength="20" type="Password" placeholder="Escriba Algo">
                </div>

                <div class="select-box">
                    <div class="options-container">
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="id_cargo" />
                            <label for="automobiles">Administrador</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="id_cargo" />
                            <label for="film">Cliente</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="selected">
                        Selecciona un cargo
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button name="submit" class="btn solid" value="Registrar" type="submit">Registrar</button>


            </form>
```

Y la conexion con la consulta.

```
include '../ConBD.php';
include '../scripts.php';
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$paterno = $_POST['paterno'];
$materno = $_POST['materno'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['contra'];
$confirmar_contra = $_POST['confirmar_contra'];
$id_cargo = $_POST['id_cargo'];

$completo = $nombre . " " . $paterno . " " . $materno;

if ($_POST["contra"] === $_POST["confirmar_contra"]) {
    $consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT into usuarios (id,nombre, paterno, materno, completo, correo, telefono, 
    usuario, contra, id_cargo) VALUES (null, '$nombre','$paterno','$materno','$completo','$correo','$telefono',
    '$usuario','$contra','$id_cargo')");
    header('location: ../Login.php?m=1');
} else {
    header('location: ../Login.php?n=1');
}
```

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿El código entra en el `if`  o no? Si entra y el INSERT no ocurre puede que: no haya conexión, haya datos incorrectos, la consulta falle por error de sintaxis, por clave duplicada, etc. Dado que no controlas nada de eso tienes un código mudo en ciertos puntos que te deja en el limbo. Tu tarea como programador es prever cualquier cosa que pueda salir mal y dar una respuesta. Falta un control de errores en el código para hacerlo robusto, a prueba de cualquier fallo. Aparte de eso, tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, pero ese es otro tema...

Comment: Entonces como me hago?

Comment: Primero pulsa en [edit]  y aclara la pregunta. ¿Qué ocurre actualmente con tu código? ¿Entra en el `if` sí o no? ¿Depuraste las variables? Puedes escribir la consulta así por ejemplo: `$sql="INSERT into usuarios (id,nombre, paterno, materno, completo, correo, telefono, usuario, contra, id_cargo) VALUES (null, '$nombre', '$paterno', '$materno', '$completo', '$correo', '$telefono', '$usuario', '$contra', '$id_cargo')";` y hacer un `echo $sql;`, revisar si la instrucción está bien, probarla directamente en el manejador, etc. Son cosas básicas de depuración de código que debes ir aprendiendo.

Comment: Ya encontre el error, los datos si estaban llegando, pero no registraba por mi lista desplegable... Pero aun asi muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. De todos modos, considera lo que te he dicho en mi comentario para implementarlo en un futuro no muy lejano.